# A page with some input boxes posts to a action, what are my options in retrieving form values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that a form posts to:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/formtest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView HandleFormPost()
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("posttest");



        return mv;
    }
```

What are my options in retrieving the data from the form?

In asp.net I would just do:

```
Request.Form["key"] or Request["key"]
```

or I could use a parameter in my action FormCollection and then just do:

```
form["key"]
```

I am using spring MVC (version 3), what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do any of the following:

```
public ModelAndView handleFormPost(WebRequest request) {
   request.getParameter("key");
}
```

or

```
public ModelAndView handleFormPost(@RequestParam String key) {

}
```

There are many other options, but these two are the easiest.

A `@RequestMapping`-annotated method can take a wide variety of different arguments (you just add them to the method and Spring will supply them), and can return a wide variety of different return types. The options are [listed here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments).

Comment: thanks! so a requestparam is either querystring or form value?

Comment: you're still thinking in ASP :)

Comment: was that an answer? now i'm confused hehe.  I need a Response.End and also!